# Dict reader python, ignore empty headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I got this piece of code -

```
try:
    with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=name, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        latestfile = None
        latest = 0
        size = 0
        for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr():
            if fileattr.filename.lower().endswith('.csv') and fileattr.st_mtime > latest:
                print(fileattr.st_size)
                size = fileattr.st_size
                print(fileattr.filename.lower())
                latest = fileattr.st_mtime
                latestfile = fileattr.filename
        if latestfile is not None:
            if size < 10000000:
                file = sftp.open(latestfile)
                reader = csv.DictReader(file)
                check = jsonify(list(reader))
                return check
            else:
                return 'big file'
        else:
            return 'none'
except: 
    return 'none ftp'
```

It connects to SFTP and reads their csv file as an array of objects.
It works amazing, the only problem is that it fails (the except gets returned) reading the file if there are some empty headers in the csv file.
How can i make it skip/ignore empty headers and still get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what i want by adding some arguments to the csv.DictReader function =

`reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',', escapechar='\\', quotechar='"')`

By that, it ignored the commas and was able to read the csv to a list.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `literal_eval()`?

```py
from ast import literal_eval
# code
literal_eval(dict, list or tuple)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did not try it yet.
Could you show me example of how to apply it on my code?

Comment: add `variable = literal_eval(dict, list or tuple string)`

Comment: turns strings into their respective type

Comment: and than what? i still did not understand what should happen

Comment: the variable you defined will be the actuall dictionary, list or tuple instead of the string and getting a TypeError

Comment: that supposed to ignore the empty headers?

Comment: i need it to read the file even with the empty header, i don't need to check the type of the variable.